# Bring Https to U-boot

Tags: u-boot

i am new to U-boot. I need to  work on bringing the HTTPS support in U-boot for arm processor and use the https apis during boot time not as a standalone application. Any pointers how to do please.

Answer (score 0):

If you need https support on U-Boot you should use the bootefi command to start the iPXE snp.efi binary as described in:

- https://www.xypron.de/projects/u-boot/iscsi.html
- http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.iscsi